# Code seems to read correctly but yet it wont run

Tags: java, class, for-loop

This may be a bit of a selfish question but something isn't right and I need a seasoned coder to help me see the unseen.

Its a simple program that stores student details from a "Student" class into an ArrayList.
It was functioning correctly until I added the for-loop. I dont have any syntax errors and nothing displays in the console.

Thanks in advanced!

```
public class Wizard
{       
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

         ArrayList<Student> studentList;

    public Wizard()
    {
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        int numberOfStudents = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter student details

        for(int n = 0; n < numberOfStudents; n=n+1)
        {

            // how many students are in the class 
                System.out.print("How many students in your class?: ");
                numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("There are " + (numberOfStudents) + " students in the class.\n");


            // what is the students name 
                System.out.print("Enter student " + (n + 1)+"'s name: ");
                String studentName = input.next();

            // what is the students grade
                System.out.print("Enter " + (studentName) + "'s grade: ");
                int studentGrade = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                        // make a new student

                Student newStudent = new Student(studentName, studentGrade);

            // Store student

                studentList.add(newStudent);
                System.out.println("Student " + newStudent.getName() + " has been added.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything in your `main` method.

Comment: "It was functioning correctly until I added the for-loop." Huh? The for loop *is* the program...

Comment: Suggest to replace the for loop with  a while loop over some boolean until it is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is `numberOfStudents` being set? You initialize the variable as `int numberOfStudents = 0;` but I can't see it getting any other value before the `for`-loop?

So basically the `for`-loop is not executed once because `numberOfStudents` is `0`.

Also if you plan to change the loop-counter-variable during the loop you should consider using a `while`-loop instead. `for`-loops are not really meant to be used when having a dynamic loop-counter-maximum.

Comment: Oh I see. 

` System.out.print("How many students in your class?: ");
                numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("There are " + (numberOfStudents) + " students in the class.\n");`

This is the line that sets the value of numberOfStudents which I have now moved outside the loop in which I still receive the same result as before. 

I'll change to a While loop and see if that helps.

Comment: Its working now! I also had an error with my main method which I had moved from another class.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it should be working if you set it outside the `for`-loop. Maybe changing `n=n+1` to `n++` would do the trick. But if it works now everything is fine anyway. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't run through the loop at all since you set `numberOfStudents` to 0.